# Rails ActiveAdmin - Edit the new resource-view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I added ActiveAdmin to my application and successfully changed the index-method for my resource. Now when I click on 'new resource' it brings me to the new-method just fine, however, there's a button missing (paperclip) in order to allow the user to upload an image-attachment.

I can not find a way to edit the view, neither do I find a way to completely rewrite the new-method.

If you need any code by me I can paste everything here.

Thanks!
// Check the very bottom of this post for the solution!

// This is how I tried it, but it's not working. The changes I applied to 'app/admin/entry.rb' for my index-method worked, but the 'new'-method just doesn't work at all.

app/admin/entry.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Entry do

  index do
    column :id
    column :description
    column :created_at
    column :image_content_type
    column do |entry|
      links = link_to "Edit", edit_admin_entry_path(entry)
      links += " "
      links += link_to "Delete", admin_entry_path(entry), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
      links
    end
  end

  def new
    form_for @entry, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
      f.label :description
      f.text_area :description
      f.file_field :image
    end
    f.submit 'Save'
  end

end
```

Before I added ActiveAdmin I just added a scaffold for Entry and used it like this:
entries_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
  end
```

View (new.html.slim):

```
h1 New entry

== render 'form'

= link_to 'Back', entries_path
```

The rendered form (_form.html.slim):

```
= form_for @entry, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  - if @entry.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this entry from being saved:"
      ul
        - @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message

  .field
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description
    = f.file_field :image
  .actions = f.submit 'Save'
```

Now, while this still works when heading to localhost:3000/entries/new it simply shows the default view for localhost:3000/admin/entries/new

If you got any help, that'd be highly appreciated!
Is there any way to see the existing code that ActiveAdmin already uses somehow? I may change it to my needs by simply adding that one field I need.

// SOLUTION:

## app/admin/resource.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Entry do
  permit_params :image, :description

  index do
    column :id
    column :description
    column :created_at
    column :image_file_name
    column :image_content_type
    column do |entry|
      links = link_to "Edit", edit_admin_entry_path(entry)
      links += " "
      links += link_to "Delete", admin_entry_path(entry), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
      links
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "New Entry" do
      f.input :description
      f.input :image
    end
    f.actions
  end

    

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize both the controller actions and the new resource view.

To edit the new action in the controller:

```
#app/admin/your_resource.rb

controller do
  def new
    @resource = Resource.new
    .... # Your custom logic goes here
  end
end
```

To edit the new resource view and add an image with paperclip.

```
#app/admin/your_resource.rb

form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  f.inputs "Resource Details" do
    f.input :title
    .... # Your input fields

    # This adds the image field. Be careful though 
    # the field name needs to be the same in your model

    f.input :image, as: :file, required: false
  end

  f.actions
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try in a few minutes!

Comment: Your welcome ! You can also check the wiki of active_admin. http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html

Comment: Hey,

I tried to apply the changes but it just does not seem to work. I edited my first post with all my necessary code and further explanations. Would be awesome if you could have another look at it.

Comment: Okay, nevermind. I'll from now on start doing it exactly as people tell me.
I updated my first post again with the actual solution.

My only question is why do I have to specify the INDEX-method, however, when I want to change the VIEW I only need 'form'? I do not see where this is documented at.